# Seaborn line across scatterplot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a seaborn scatterplot across categories (y-axis) with time on the x-axis:

```
z=sns.scatterplot(data=df], x="transaction_date", y="product_name", hue="source_of_business",s=100)
```

What's the best way to add a line across each date category combination like below

Comment: "What's the best way to add a line across each date category combination "

Comment: @JDoe it would help to provide the dataset as dataframe constructor

Comment: You have a sample dataset so people can reproduce?

Comment: dataset added in the main thread

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting up a line chart using data frames extracted by product name.

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="transaction_date", y="product_name", hue="source_of_business", s=100)
for c in df['product_name'].unique():
    dfq = df.query('product_name == @c').reset_index()
    sns.lineplot(data=dfq, x='transaction_date',y='product_name', color='black', ax=ax)
```

[image]